# Text Cleaning and Stopwords

Tags: python, machine-learning, text

I am trying to complete a text learning project for a machine learning class. I was given the following function by my teacher and I don't understand why I'm getting the error I'm getting. This function is supposed to take a string of words, remove the punctuation and stop words, and return the new string.

```
def review_to_words( raw_review ):
    # Function to convert a raw review to a string of words
    # The input is a single string (a raw movie review), and 
    # the output is a single string (a preprocessed movie review)
    #
    # 1. Remove HTML
    review_text = BeautifulSoup(raw_review).get_text() 
    #
    # 2. Remove non-letters (punctuation)       
    letters_only = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", review_text) 
    #
    # 3. Convert to lower case, split into individual words
    words = letters_only.lower().split()                             
    #
    # 4. In Python, searching a set is much faster than searching
    #   a list, so convert the stop words to a set
    stops = set(stopwords.words("english"))                  
    # 
    # 5. Remove stop words
    meaningful_words = [w for w in words if not w in stops]   
    #
    # 6. Join the words back into one string separated by space, 
    # and return the result.
    return( " ".join( meaningful_words ))

clean_review = review_to_words(first1000["review"][0] )
```

It says there is a key error with 'review' in the following line:

```
clean_review = review_to_words(first1000["review"][0] )
```

first1000 is a variable set to:

```
first1000 = data["review"][0:1000]
```

My dataset is a .tsv file containing several thousand movie reviews from imdb. The variable 'review' is just one review from that dataset.

Again, this function is supposed to take a string of words, remove the punctuation and stop words, and return the new string. I'm not sure what is going on, because I have looked over the code and it looks fine to me.

EDIT: What I'm hearing from the responses so far is, my data is a dictionary of lists. That sounds correct. Each review is a list of words, and the whole dataset is a list of reviews. But now I need to find a method to count the number of lists in the dictionary. What I currently have is:

```
num_reviews = count(train_reviews["reviews"])
print(num_reviews)
```

where train_reviews["reviews"] is a subset of my data. It is still a dictionary of lists. I need to count how many lists there are in train_reviews. I did not get an error with this code, but I did not get any output either. I know for sure it should have produced some output from the print command, which is why I'm confused.

P.S. If I'm supposed to make a whole new question in order to post about a new problem with the same code, please just tell me and I will remember that in the future.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: I'm assuming you have a `dict` with `lists` as values for `data`. Since you have not shown us how `data` is formatted, I'm assuming that `first1000` is a `list` of 1000 words and not a `dict`. Otherwise you would have done something like `first1000 = {"review" : data["review"][0:1000]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have a dict `data` with various data entries, one of which is under the key `"review"`.  This data entries is a sequence of some sort, perhaps a list of lines (strings).

You swept the first 1000 lines into a new list, `first1000`.  This is a `list`, not a `dict` -- it doesn't have any keys.  You have a sequence of 1000 strings in this variable -- there is no "review" entry.

Remove the `["review"]` element from your call and see what you get.  Better yet, learn some basic debugging: print out the values you're using, to make sure they match what you *think* they hold.

See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Comment: It's a critical skill.  If I can help the poster so he doesn't even have to *ask* the next question, then everybody wins.

Comment: @Prune This...This is what I like to see.

Comment: I have removed the    ["review"] element from my call, and it gave me the clean review that I was expecting. I am currently working my way through the debug blog you linked.

Comment: Any recommended ways to debug a python program?

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Debug Python program", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting the error because `data["review"][0:1000]` is likely a `list` (or some iterable), not a dictionary. If so, to fix it, just do `first1000[0]` instead. Impossible to tell since you haven't provided an MVCE, though.

Here's a (smaller) example:

```
In [4]: data = {'review': list(range(10000))}

In [5]: data['review'][0:10]
Out[5]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [6]: first10 = data['review'][0:10]

In [7]: first10[0]
Out[7]: 0
```

So, when you access a dictionary item with a given key, then you get whatever that key is *pointing to*, and *not* the key itself. Since it's just a `list`, you'll get a key error if you try to use the key `'review'`, since `list` can only take integer indices:

```
In [8]: first10['review'][0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-61dfa9e84754> in <module>()
----> 1 first10['review'][0]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

HTH.